# Can I translate a stacktrace from minified code into a human readable stacktrace using sourcemaps?

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, source-maps, minifiedjs

I have some errors from minified code in production. I have sourcemaps not in production. I'd like to (after the fact) use source maps in a way to convert my stack trace into a human readable stack trace. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am also doing some research on the same, and come up with some reference. I am sharing those for you:

- https://github.com/janekp/mapstrace
- https://github.com/novocaine/sourcemapped-stacktrace
- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/05/compiling-to-javascript-and-debugging-with-source-maps/

Answer (score 3):

[Raygun](https://raygun.com/) developed a [Source Maps Validator](https://raygun.com/validatesourcemaps) which let's you upload your source map file.

If you do that, then you can take the **line number** and **column number** from the stacktrace of your minified sourcecode to identify the original source which is causing the problem.

**Example:**

Stacktrace on production (in `.min.js` file)

```
Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at https://app.wire.com/min/wire-vendor.min.js?2016-06-06-15-36-prod:15:25804
```

Reading the stacktrace, the line number is **15** and the column number is **25804** (last two parts of the url).

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not available anymore 